# Use of data from ROC curve

Tags: survival, cox-model, roc

In order to find an optimal time for initiation of treatment post surgery (oncologic patients) I created a ROC curve with death defined as event.
The AUC was not significant. However, I decided to use the time that provided the best specificity and sensitivity in cox regression as a binary variable.
The Cox parameter was significant.
I was wondering whether I am committing a sin using data from ROC curve with p-value > 0.05 and by using the data obtained from exploratory analysis to analyse the same training data.
I would be very interested in hearing feedback and suggestions (maybe for validation?)

Thanks in advance,
Liran

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how you could find the optimal time without using utilities and incorporating uncertainty.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a binary variable based in the "best" cutpoint (best sens. and spec.) is not surprising you have a Cox regression with a significant P-value, but the issue this test is not correct now. The selection of the best cutpoint is a similar idea to analysis the máximum of all the statistics over all possible cutpoints.
A suggestion is test the significance by permutations, where the censored label and survival times are permuted and the whole analysis is repeated ( search of the best cutpoint and Cox regression with the binary variable )